# Populate a hidden field with h1 tag OR URL

Tags: javascript, html, forms, return-value, hidden-field

So I thought this would be easy but it hasn't yielded any results (yet). I have a form that I have created and want to put it on a couple of different pages. What I want to do is have it so that when the form is completed and sent it will populate that hidden field with either the h1 tag of the page or the URL (which ever is easiest).

I have a form with the a hidden field: `<input type="hidden" name="myField" value="America">`

Ideally I would like to use javascript.

Thanks everyone!

p.s. I can't use URL parameters because the parameters are made by my cms and don't mean anything to me.

Comment: You should be more clear in what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

You can set the field value using javascript and `location.href` to get the url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementsByName("myField")[0].value = location.href</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a script-tag in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(){
        document.getElementsById("IdOfHiddenField").value = location.href;
        return;
    }
</script>
```

And your form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="..." onsubmit="return submitForm()" method="post">
    ...buttons, fields and the hidden input-field...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```